# Error while authenticating using certificate to RabbitMq using .net sdk

Tags: c#, ssl, rabbitmq, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

The certificate was issued by "Go Daddy" and we have the intermediate and the root already available with the Windows certificate store. The path to the certificate and the password are correct. I don't know why it throws certificate chain is issued by an untrusted authority. We also included the "SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateChainErrors" to ignore such chain errors but the SDK throws the error. Any help?
Code:

```
ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ConnectionFactory
                {
                    HostName = _rabbitConnectionConfiguration.HostName,
                    Port = _rabbitConnectionConfiguration.Port,
                    VirtualHost = _rabbitConnectionConfiguration.VirtualHost,
                };
connectionFactory.UserName = null;
                            connectionFactory.Password = null;
                            connectionFactory.AuthMechanisms = new IAuthMechanismFactory[] { new ExternalMechanismFactory() };

                            var sslOption = new SslOption
                            {
                                Enabled = true,
                                ServerName = _rabbitConnectionConfiguration.HostName,
                                CertPath = _rabbitConnectionConfiguration.CertPath,
                                AcceptablePolicyErrors = SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateNameMismatch | SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateChainErrors,
                                CertPassphrase = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_rabbitConnectionConfiguration.CertPassword) ? string.Empty : _rabbitConnectionConfiguration.CertPassword,
                                Version = _rabbitConnectionConfiguration.Version
                            };

                            connectionFactory.Ssl = sslOption;
```

Error:

```
None of the specified endpoints were reachable
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 
The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted

   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.InternalEndProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.EndProcessAuthentication(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.SslHelper.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<TcpUpgrade>b__0(SslOption opts)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.SslHelper.TcpUpgrade(Stream tcpStream, SslOption options)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.SocketFrameHandler..ctor(AmqpTcpEndpoint endpoint, Func`2 socketFactory, TimeSpan connectionTimeout, TimeSpan readTimeout, TimeSpan writeTimeout)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.CreateFrameHandler(AmqpTcpEndpoint endpoint)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.EndpointResolverExtensions.SelectOne[T](IEndpointResolver resolver, Func`2 selector)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at RabbitMQ.Client.EndpointResolverExtensions.SelectOne[T](IEndpointResolver resolver, Func`2 selector)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.Framing.Impl.AutorecoveringConnection.Init(IEndpointResolver endpoints)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(IEndpointResolver endpointResolver, String clientProvidedName)
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.InternalEndProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.EndProcessAuthentication(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.SslHelper.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<TcpUpgrade>b__0(SslOption opts)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.SslHelper.TcpUpgrade(Stream tcpStream, SslOption options)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.SocketFrameHandler..ctor(AmqpTcpEndpoint endpoint, Func`2 socketFactory, TimeSpan connectionTimeout, TimeSpan readTimeout, TimeSpan writeTimeout)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.CreateFrameHandler(AmqpTcpEndpoint endpoint)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.EndpointResolverExtensions.SelectOne[T](IEndpointResolver resolver, Func`2 selector)<---
```

Comment: The way c# tests for SSL (really TLS) issue is using a timeout when the connection does not complete.  Connection can fail to complete for lots of reasons.  So issue may not be SSL.  Certificates can be used for more both TLS and Authentication and a different Certificate may be use for TLS and Authentication.  See : https://www.rabbitmq.com/troubleshooting.html

Comment: But this error is only if use go daddy certificate. If I use any other, the error message is different.  If the connection does not complete why would i get chain trust error and that too this is at client side.

Comment: There are two certificates 1) For TLS 2) Authentication  Without seeing the second error message I cannot tell exactly what is happening.  Do you get back a Response.  If TLS fails you do not get back a response.  A response only occurs when TLS passes.

Comment: The rabbit mq SDK takes only one certificate while authenticating. So I guess it uses the same for both.

Comment: The error message when I use another certificate :
"None of the specified endpoints were reachable      at RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(IEndpointResolver endpointResolver, String clientProvidedName)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(String clientProvidedName)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection()
   at RabbitMqCertCheck.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\anagendr\source\repos\RabbitMqCertCheck\Program.cs:line 66System.IO.IOException: No compatible authentication mechanism found - server offered [PLAIN]"

Comment: There are two different certificates.  TLS is done before the request is sent and is not part of RabbitMQ.  The new error message indicates the connection never completed which is probably TLS.  The original error message is authentication.  So go back to original certificate.  You have an authentication issue.  Use my original troubleshooting link.

Comment: I maintain the C# RabbitMQ client. I'm sure I can figure this out, but Stack Overflow is a _terrible_ means to do so. If you would like assistance, please start a discussion here and I will see it: https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-dotnet-client/discussions. Please include your COMPLETE RabbitMQ configuration, C# code, and ideally, certificates (including public and private keys). Obviously for the latter you will have to generate test certs. If you can't provide your own certs, I will use my own from [tls-gen](https://github.com/rabbitmq/tls-gen). Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-dotnet-client/discussions/1367
Please help @LukeBakken